# $addToSet aggregation and multiple arrays

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this collection :

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId('myId1'),
        probes: ['id_probe_1', 'id_probe_2']
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId('myId2'),
        probes: ['id_probe_1', 'id_probe_3']
    }
]
```

I want to get an array like this :

```
['id_probe_1', 'id_probe_2', 'id_probe_3']
```

So I try this request (from nodeJS driver) :

```
let find = [
    {
        $match: {
            _id: {
                $in: [new ObjectId('miId1'), new ObjectId('myId2')]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            probes: {
                $addToSet: {
                    $each: '$probes'
                }
            }
        }
    }
];
```

This doesn't work, give me this error :

> invalid operator '$each'

From the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/), they mention that it will appends the whole array as a single element.

> If the value of the expression is an array, $addToSet appends the whole array as a single element.

But they don't say how to have an unique array. So I use the $each operator like [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) indicates (I don't really know what's the difference...)

Is there a way to make this work ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

insert `$unwind` before `$group`

```
  {$unwind:"$probes"},
```

then remove `$each`

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try distinct operation? In mongo shell,  `db.col.distinct('probs');` you can try the distinct function in nodejs mongo driver.

Comment: Thanks ! It works too, but I also needed to make some adjustment on top of that :)